# How to override imported styling with tailwind

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have a react project where I use tailwind. I have an index.css file that I am importing at the root of my project. The index.css file looks like this:

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "@navikt/ds-css";
@import "@navikt/ui-common/styles/index.css";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
@import "custom.css";
```

I would like to override classes that I import with the styles in custom.css. The custom.css looks like this:

```
.navds-tabs__tablist-wrapper {
    width: max-content;
}
.navds-checkbox__label {
    align-items: center;
}
.navds-checkbox__icon {
    max-height: 0.5rem;
}
.navds-date__field-input {
    width: 144px;
}
```

My tailwind.config.cjs file looks like this:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Also, postcss.config.cjs looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    "postcss-import": {},
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

I use webpack for building a project and this is the config I use:

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const { ModuleFederationPlugin } = require("webpack").container;
const deps = require("./package.json").dependencies;
const { EsbuildPlugin } = require("esbuild-loader");

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.tsx",
    output: {
        filename: "[name].[fullhash].js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist"),
    },
    experiments: {
        topLevelAwait: true,
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js", ".jsx"],
    },
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            new EsbuildPlugin({
                target: "ESNext",
                minify: false,
                format: "esm",
                sourcemap: true,
                minifyIdentifiers: false,
                minifyWhitespace: true,
                minifySyntax: true,
                globalName: "case_ui",
                css: true,
                keepNames: true,
            }),
        ],
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader", "postcss-loader"],
            },
            {
                test: /\.([jt]sx?)?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "esbuild-loader",
                options: {
                    target: "ESNext",
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.svg$/,
                loader: "svg-inline-loader",
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            process: "process/browser",
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "[name].[fullhash].css",
            ignoreOrder: true,
        }),
        new ModuleFederationPlugin({
            name: "case_ui",
            filename: "remoteEntry.js",
            exposes: {
                "./Prehandling": "./src/app.tsx",
                "./Case": "./src/app.tsx",
            },
            shared: {
                react: { singleton: true, requiredVersion: deps.react },
                "react-dom": { singleton: true, requiredVersion: deps.react },
            },
        }),
    ],
};
```

I wonder why don't classes that I have in custom.css override classes that I import in index.css?
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Consider checking:

- The [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) of rules that have declarations you want to override.

  It could be that your custom rules (which all have specificity 0-1-0), do not have high enough specificity to override the rules defined in other CSS files you have `@import`ed.

  You could look at increasing the specificity of your rules to resolve this.
- Your CSS rules match what you intend. It could be that your CSS rules don't actually match the HTML elements you wish to style. Consider consulting the developer tools to check your CSS rules are being applied.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an ongoing issue with react, please see this:
[PostCSS Import Order with base styles not working](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/7049)

The merge request from the op [fix: allow custom config file for postcss again](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/11926)

suggests removing `config: false,` from webpack.config.js: [commit](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/11926/commits/0c5305d08da01dc55b283e0df5acfb12f12b815c)

You can also use the rules from your custom.css directly(inline) in index.css instead of importing.